# Python recursive list search function

Tags: python, list, search, recursion

I have to write a recursive function to search a list for a specific value. The function is supposed to find whether or not the number is in the list and if it is it will return the list index of that value.

For example:

```
search([1,2,3,4,5],3)
```

should return:

```
2
```

as 3 appears in list index 2.

Right now I have:

```
def search(myList, number):
    if myList[0] == number:
        return myList[0]
    return search(myList[1:], number)
```

and it keeps returning 3 for the same function call I had earlier. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to use recursion?  List already provides this method `list.index`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes in your current code, you return the number iteself, instead of its index, and you don't really pass the incremented index back. So, do this instead:

```
>>> def search(myList, number):
...     if myList[0] == number:
...         return 0
...     return 1 + search(myList[1:], number)
... 
>>> search([1,2,3,4,5],3)
2
```

---

Now that works if we have the number within the list, but if not, we will get an index error.

```
>>> search([1,2,3,4,5],6)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So, we should wrap the function in a try-except block

```
def search(myList, number):
    def search_recursive(lst, num):
        if lst[0] == num:
            return 0
        return 1 + search_recursive(lst[1:], num)
    try: return search_recursive(myList, number)
    except IndexError: return -1
```

And now, it will work

```
>>> search([1,2,3,4,5],6)
-1
>>> search([1,2,3,4,5],5)
4
```

---

But the above should be used only when you want to do this recursively, and note that when you do `list[1:]`, you perform list slicing which creates a new list everytime.

So, if doing this without recursion is allowed, use the builtin `list.index` method:

```
>>> def search(my_list, number):
...     try: return my_list.index(number)
...     except ValueError: return -1
... 
>>> search([1,2,3,4,5],5)
4
>>> search([1,2,3,4,5],6)
-1
```

Comment: Or... you could just wrap the if statement in a try except block.

Comment: @jakekimds That was my hunch as well, but just putting the if within the try except won't work, why don't you try doing that :)

Comment: Oh. I see. The recursiveness is interfering.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `index` built-in method:

```
>>> def search(my_list, val):
...     try:
...         return my_list.index(val)
...     except valueError:
...         return "not found"
...
>>> search([1,2,3,4,5],3)
2
```